# How to sum difference in time between two metrics over last 30 days in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to compile some stats over last 30 days of metrics. I want to sum the diffence over time of kube_job_status_completion_time and kube_job_status_start_time

```
sum(max_over_time(kube_job_status_completion_time[30d] - kube_job_status_start_time[30d]))
```

I get the following error

> Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 86: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types.

Any suggestion on how I should proceed?

My goal is to plot an instant bar graph in grafana showing last 30 days sum of computation time for every namespace.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it

```
sum(max_over_time(kube_job_status_completion_time[30d]) - min_over_time(kube_job_status_start_time[30d])) by (namespace)
```